# Debugging embedded framework not working as expected when debugging super classes or protocol extensions/implementations

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

I wrote a pure Swift framework which I am embedding inside my project.

Debugging is working fine when I debug code that I am using straight from my app.

For example, if I write a `Dog` class inside the framework with a method and I call it from my app, everything is fine.

But, if I write a base class like `Animal` and then a `Dog` class inside my app module that inherits from Animal and the breakpoint reaches the implementations on `Animal`, it shows like this:

[image: breakpoint]

The same occurs if `Animal` is a protocol and I write an extension or default implementation inside it and I call the method from an instance of `Dog`.

I already checked that I am indeed running the framework in debug mode, with no optimization, not stripping symbols and also using `DWARF` and `dSYM`.

Comment: I think you should report that as a bug

Comment: What's the swift version you are using for?

Comment: I set up a simple project with a framework in a workspace and I am not having this issue. Xcode 8.3

Comment: This happens in swift 3.0, xcode 8.3

Comment: are you able to see values with "po"?

Comment: po prints an error

Comment: Sometimes Xcode behaves odd, make sure you didn't stop a Xcode upgrade while it started. Or try uninstalling Xcode and install.

Comment: Now I am working on Xcode 9 beta 6 and the problem persists

Comment: @DavidBemerguy, Not having this issue with Xcode 9/Swift 4 project. Could you please upload a sample project and link it here?

Comment: if you press one of the frames does the debugger jump to that line in code?

Comment: Is `MagistoCore` the name of your framework? It's hard to see what's the "Animal" and what's the "Dog", as you describe it, in the screenshot stack-trace.

Comment: Is it possible you're referring to this bug? http://www.openradar.me/23551273

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue in Xcode, I met same in 9.2. I always clear the derrived data and clean project/ rebuild and it works.